# Laravel 5 middleware allow specific view depending on type of user

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am a beginner in laravel.

I am trying to make a section just for a user that contains the 'ADM' type, that is defined in the table users.

If users is 'ADM' type, redirect to the adm view, else redirect to something else.

I've created a middleware for that, works perfectly, except when I try to to verify the type of the user with a function in the User model.

When I go to route /adm and call the middleware. the browser gives me an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

The code in my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if(User::IsAdm()) {
        return redirect('adm');
    } else {
        return redirect('404');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

My function on User model:

```
public static function IsAdm() {
    if (\Auth::check()) {
        $loggedUser = \Auth::user();
        if($loggedUser->type == 'ADM') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention that.
When I go to route /adm and call the middleware. the browser gives me an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Read through your logic line by line. On the `adm` route, your checking if the user is of type `adm`, if they are you redirect to the `adm` route... you have a recursive redirect loop.

Comment: I change the code and now is working, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, and it's working fine for me.
 Try to see if you are loading the correct view, or make sure that the `type` property exist as a db column in the users table.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention that.
When I go to route /adm and call the middleware. the browser gives me an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Answer (score 0):

I change the code to this, and now it works perfectly.

Thanks to @jeemusu

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
if(!User::IsAdm()) {
    return redirect('404');
} 

return $next($request);
```

}